# Find points in an area

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given 4 points of an area, I want to calculate 30 random points inside the area. Is there a way to do that fast? I ask this because if there is a library to do that I could calculate more than 30 random points.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean 4 corners? Find the transform that maps your shape to a square, calculate random uniform coordinates in the square, then map back to your shape with the inverse transform.